# IIS Output Caching for Blazor Server Self Contained App

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, blazor, blazor-server-side, outputcache

I'm hosting a Blazor Server app (Self contained publish/deployment mode) in IIS 10.

I'm familiar with setting up Output Caching for older ASP.net projects, **and would like to use it to cache static files inside the Blazor project (css, js, png, jpg).**

After setting up User Mode & Kernel Mode caching in IIS, I run the following command to confirm cache entries

```
netsh http show cachestate
```

Result:

```
There were no cache entries corresponding to the provided URL
```

I'm suspecting that is because the project was published as Self Contained.

**Should I be using ASP.NET core's Middleware Output caching for static files like JS, CSS, JPG?**

Comment: How many times did the browser request those files? Note that IIS won't cache them in the first run.

Comment: @LexLi I tried multiple times

Comment: Then you can follow the troubleshooting guide, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-modules-features/troubleshooting-iis-compression-issues-in-iis6-iis7x

Answer (score 2):

Try this caching strategy of static files inside wwwroot:

```cs
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
    {
        const int durationInSeconds = 60 * 60 * 24;
        ctx.Context.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] = "public,max-age=" + durationInSeconds;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for replying @DM-98. If I understand correctly it modifies HTTP header, so wouldn't this be Client-Side caching by the browser?

Comment: Blazor Server had a wwwroot that serves static files to the user, and it's being cached. In this example, it's 24 hours. Note - if u change the files or so, end users might see the old ones up to 24h.

Comment: thanks @DM-98 - yes that would be client-side caching. Looking for server-side IIS Output Caching. This way frequently accessed static files would live in Kernel memory instead of being read from disk every time.